# How to set Visibility of ListView to GONE when animation is finished in android?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have used move left and move right animation using xml to move my list left and right on the screen.

It works fine when set animation and it moves to the left and right perfectly and I have used the setVisibility of my list in onAnimationEnd() to gone and set the alpha to (0) and it hides.

But if I click on the previous place of my list I can select its item :( I don't know why it's still in this place

> this is my move_left.xml

```
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    >

   <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="-25%p"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

> this is my move_right.xml

```
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    >

   <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-25%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%p"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

> here is my code to hide listView

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

```
if(animation.equals(move_right)){
    verticalListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    verticalListView.setAlpha(1);
}
```

}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

```
if(animation.equals(move_left)){
    verticalListView.setAlpha(0);
    verticalListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    verticalListView.setClickable(false);
}
```

}

> this method I used to start animation and hide/show my list

```
private void showHideList(){
    if (!isShowing) {
        isShowing = true;
        verticalListView.startAnimation(move_left);
    }else{
        isShowing = false;
        verticalListView.startAnimation(move_right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your java code?

Comment: @erad ok i will post it

Comment: how you set the visibility? something like myListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: @huertazx yes i used this

Comment: Try logging the touches. Can you check that `(animation.equals(move_left))` is called?

Comment: @erad yes it called and mylist gone but the prblem is when i click on the previous place of my list i can select its items :(

Comment: just to be clear - you're trying to animate and hide your *entire* list? or just a specific list *item* ?

Comment: @Gil Moshayof yes i want to animate and then hide it because when animate it goes out side off screen but when i click on its previous place i see it hide but its items can selected :(

Comment: you did not answer my question. are you trying to hide the WHOLE LIST, or just a single item in the list?

Comment: @Gil Moshayof yes the whole list

Comment: Which one is showing or hiding the list, move_left or move_right?

Comment: @Faruk Yazıcı move_left to hide list , move_right to show list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your adapter add this:

```
private boolean isListEnabled = true;

public void setListEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
     this.isListEnabled = isEnabled;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
     return isListEnabled;
}
```

by default your list will be enabled, add this for disable:

```
@Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
     if(animation.equals(move_left)){
        verticalListView.setAlpha(0);
        verticalListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        verticalListView.setClickable(false);
        yourAdapter.setListEnabled(false);
     }
}
```

to enable again just send true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Runnable()`. I can see that you animation lasts for 500 milliseconds. Then, you can adjust the visibilities as follows;

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                            verticalListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        }, 500);
```

So that animation starts, and after 500 miliseconds, the listView disappears.

Try to use it here,

```
private void showHideList(){
if (!isShowing) {
    isShowing = true;
    verticalListView.startAnimation(move_left);
     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                            verticalListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        }, 500);
}else{
    isShowing = false;
    verticalListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    verticalListView.startAnimation(move_right);

}
}
```

Comment: I need more details of your code :( For example, when do you call these if statements to hide or show listViews? Do you have a button? If you have a button, you can just add this code after the animation codes. But need more details.